# Random redirect with the help of PHP

Tags: php, redirect, refresh

i am trying to make random redirect using `header refresh` in PHP. for some reason i cannot use `header location`.

The code placed in `example.org`

```
$url = array('https://example.com/','https://example.net/');
shuffle($url);
header("refresh: 0;url=$url");
```

This redirecting to `example.org/Array` instead of the urls

If i use like `header("refresh: 0;url=$url[0]");` it redirecting to example.com but i want to make it random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
$url = ['https://example.com','https://example.net'];
        $size = count($url);
        $random=rand(0, $size - 1);
        header("refresh: 0;url=$url[$random]");
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i have nowhere mentioned my own answer is better than anyone. I was keep trying and suddenly this worked and i thought posting it here. I do respect every contributor who taken there valuable time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

To select random value from array first you need to select random key from array
and then value like this

```
$url = array('https://example2.co/','https://example33.net/');
$key = array_rand($url);
$new_url = $url[$key];

header("refresh: 0;url=$new_url");
```

Answer (score 0):

With only two items in the array you're quite likely to get the same thing every time.

You could do something like this with `array_rand`

```php
$url = array('https://example.com/','https://example.net/');
$key = array_rand($url, 1);
header("refresh: 0; url={$url[$key]}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of URLs & just shuffle between those to pick at random. Then once one is picked you can header refresh to that URL:

```php
    $url = array('https://google.com/','https://yahoo.com/');
    shuffle($url);
    $rand_url = $url[rand()&1];
    header("refresh: 0;url=$rand_url");
```